# Error: Initial value to non-const must be an lvalue

Tags: c++, iterator, lvalue

I'm getting a C2440 ('initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::_Vb_reference<_Alloc>' to 'bool &'), which IntelliSense translates to the error in the title.

I get what this error is saying, just not why it's being said.  The code below produces this error:

```
std::vector<const UINT>::iterator oIter;

oIter = std::find(vecuClassID.begin(), vecuClassID.end(), uClassID);

const UINT uDistance = std::distance(vecuClassID.begin(), oIter);

bool& refbStaticSectionInitialized = *(vecbStaticSectionInitialized.begin() + uDistance);
```

The error seems to occur at the last line - in Visual Studio, the dereference operator is underlined in red.  This is confusing because I have code that does the exact same thing with CRITICAL_SECTION, and that produces no error:

```
std::vector<const UINT>::iterator oIter;

oIter = std::find(vecuClassID.begin(), vecuClassID.end(), uClassID);

const UINT uDistance = std::distance(vecuClassID.begin(), oIter);

CRITICAL_SECTION& refhStaticSection = *(vechStaticSection.begin() + uDistance);
```

Does it have something to do with bool being a primitive?

Comment: What is `vecbStaticSectionInitialized`

Comment: It's a std::vector of bools.  vechStaticSection is a vector of CRITICAL_SECTIONs.

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` is somewhat "broken" in that it doesn't always work like you'd expect. Check a reference.

Comment: Well I switched to the Windows macro BOOL (int) and now there's no issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `std::vector<bool>` doesn't return `bool&` from its subscript operator or when dereferencing its iterator. Instead, the type returned is `std::vector<bool>::reference` which is a class **not** converting to `bool&`.

The misguided idea behind `std::vector<bool>` is to adjust the interface to allow a packed representation. Since a bit isn't addressable, `std::vector<bool>::reference` works as a proxy for a bit.